# What to unit test - simple validation class

Tags: android, unit-testing

I'm learning about unit testing in Android (and in general).

For practice, I built a simple input validator class, that checks the validity of an email and password input.

It has 2 methods:

- isEmailValid(String email) - checks that the email is not null, not empty and is a valid email.
- isPasswordValid(String password) - checks that the password is not null or empty

So I thought of creating the following tests:

- email = "" - return *false*
- email = null - return *false*
- email = "aaa" - return *false*
- email = "a@valid.email" - return **true**
- password = "" - return *false*
- password = null - return *false*
- password = "pass" - return **true**

Did I get it right? Or is this a "testing overkill"?

Comment: I finished this very simple project and uploaded it to github: https://github.com/dors/simple-android-validator-unit-test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say it is not overkill. It depends on how they are written in JUnit code and how the code is written initially. Each test does check a different logical path, and with Android being user focussed these scenarios are important to check, as users will do surprising things.

For example each test should only do a single assert is usually good practice to ensure it is testing a single unit. 
Have you tested the error handling parts of the code? And any possible branches?

Also could look at using [ECLEmma](http://www.eclemma.org/) to check your code coverage to check that it is covering the code sufficiently and provide a metric. This only seems to work when using JUnit with the standard launcher, it depends what environment you are using, and if you are simply doing JUnit test with no android code. From the comment using Roboelectric an alternative method and tutorial can be found [here](http://raptordigital.blogspot.co.uk/2014/08/code-coverage-reports-using-robolectric.html) for code coverage.

You may also want to look at using [Robotium](https://code.google.com/p/robotium/wiki/RobotiumTutorials) to perform system level (User Interface) tests where user interaction can be tested.

I would also say read about unit testing in general. The test should be isolated, using Mock objects will help this and will improve dependency injection in the code. Examples are [JMockit](http://jmockit.org/) or [Mockito](http://mockito.org/). These will make your life easier when testing with for example SQLite. Enabling unit tests to focus on testing a single class will improve dependency injection and your overall design.

Tests should also keep the clean code standards as your application code, where they should be readable for future users to understand.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! There are no mocks needed for this simple project IMO. Also, I use RobolectricTestRunner, so that I will be able to use classes like TextUtils from my junit tests

Comment: @dors No problem. I have added a link for code coverage and Roboelectric.